# What do you call an object that only stores some data in it?

Tags: php, oop

In my application, I want to wrap the response I get from a third-party API into an object, so that I can easily retrieve the different properties through getters, instead of doing something like this every time.

```
if (isset($response->text) === true) {
    // some code here
}
```

In other words, this object will have no behavior of its own. It merely accepts the json data in its constructor, and returns the key from the json data in the relevant getter function if it exists. If the key doesn't exist, it simply returns null.

What are objects like this (which are meant for transferring packaged data from one object to the other) called? Are these `domain transfer objects`?

Comment: Perhaps it's better suited on programmers.stackexchange.com!

Comment: I'd be tempted to say "dictionary" since it sounds like it's just key-value pairs.

Comment: It sounds like it's more of a helper class. In that it's responsibility would be to simply unpack the retrieved API object, so you can query it more easily. So it would work in effect like a model, but without any save functionality.

Comment: @diggersworld, exactly. It is not a helper object IMO since it doesn't "help" anyone since it doesn't contain a functionality of its own. However, it does act like an entity (or as you said, a model without a `save()` function).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've always heard them referred to as a "bag of data" class. They don't do anything magical on their own, they just provide a way of organizing data to be processed elsewhere.

I think their more correct name is either a "Record", or "Plain-Old-Data" class. 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Passive_data_structure

Comment: Whenever I've seen `databags`, they have usually been a bag where you can put data in and pull data out of. However, this is just one single object that is just meant to provide a better implementation of the API response, something better than `stdClass`.

Comment: This fits I believe. A response from an API will probably have maybe a response code, a d the resulting response data, which in the end are just 2 pieces of data to be used elsewhere.